# Matlab solve overdetermined system gives wrong answer

Tags: matlab

```
gam = 1 / (2^0.5);

R = [1 0 gam 0 0 -1 -gam 0 0 0;
    0 0 gam 0 1 0 gam 0 0 0;
    0 gam 0 1 0 0 0 -gam -1 0;
    0 -gam 0 0 -1 0 0 -gam 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 1 0 gam 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 gam 0 1;
    0 0 0 0 0 0 gam 0 1 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 0 -gam 0 0 -1];

% 8 rows, 10 columns

f = 1.0e+04 *

         0
   -1.9799
    0.4243
    4.3000
         0
    0.1000
         0
    1.2728
    1.0000
   -0.8000
```

I want to solve R'*a = f. Using a = R'\f gives

```
a =

   1.0e+04 *

   -0.9727
    3.5182
    3.3273
    4.1818
   -0.5636
    9.2545
    4.6364
    9.7455
```

However

```
R'*a = 1.0e+04 *

   -0.9727
   -0.6043
    1.7999
    3.3273
   -0.6636
    0.4091
   -0.4371
    0.8357
    1.3091
   -0.4909
```

This is not f. Is that because there is no solution? How do you solve it?

Comment: What's with all the *asd* in your question?

Comment: You better use Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of matrix, the proper command in Matlab is **pinv** not **inv**

Comment: I think there is no solution to the set of equations you provide. If you try solving your system by hand, you'll end up with a contradictory statement.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, an over-determined system does not have a solution. As outlined in [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html), Using `\` (left division) on an over-determined system gives that result which is closest to being a solution in the least squares sense.

Comment: @A.Donda Let's not be pedantic. "the least squares solution" means "the solution that minimizes the sum of the squares of the errors for each equation". That is clear in my answer.